# stereoeffect not proper, the objective is to load the model opened using gltf loader into both sides, to view the model in mobile vr

Tags: gltf, threejs-editor

Here is the code which I am running on local server using nodejs, what changes I will need to make?
output: chair gets loaded into complete screen, screen doesn't get halved, such as to view in mobile vr
Expected : the screen should split into 2 halves, so as view the vr in mobile, with the 3d model opened in both the sides of the screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - GLTFloader</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="info">
        VRPage
    </div>

    <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
    <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

    <script type="module">

        import * as THREE from 'three';

        import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
        import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
        import { StereoEffect } from 'three/addons/effects/StereoEffect.js';

        let camera, scene, renderer, effect;

        init();
        render();

        function init() {

            const container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
            camera.position.set(- 1.8, 0.6, 2.7);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            new RGBELoader()
                .setPath('textures/equirectangular/')
                .load('royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function (texture) {

                    texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

                    scene.background = texture;
                    scene.environment = texture;

                    render();

                    // model

                    //const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/' );
                    const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('assets/ar-shop/')
                    loader.load('Chair4.glb', function (gltf) {

                        scene.add(gltf.scene);

                        render();

                    });

                });

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
            renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
            renderer.useLegacyLights = false;
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            effect = new StereoEffect(renderer);
            effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.addEventListener('change', render); // use if there is no animation loop
            controls.minDistance = 2;
            controls.maxDistance = 10;
            controls.target.set(0, 0, - 0.2);
            controls.update();

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            //effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            //render();

        }

        // function onWindowResize() {

        //  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        //  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        //  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        //  render();

        // }

        //

        function render() {

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```